# Google calendar get events

Tags: events, get, google-calendar-api

I am using this code and getting the events from the calendar and it is working fine but, I want to get the events from google accounts calendar .For example, I want to get the (deepakcando90@gmail.com )google calendar accounts events also? I know it is possible but do not know how to implement it?

```
      public static void readCalendarEvent(Context context) throws ParseException {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String dtstart = "dtstart";
    String dtend = "dtend";


    SimpleDateFormat    displayFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");

     stime=displayFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());     

    SimpleDateFormat startFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    String dateString = startFormatter.format(calendar.getTime());

    long after = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat formatterr = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss MM/dd/yy");
    Calendar endOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date dateCCC = formatterr.parse("47:59:59 " + dateString);
    endOfDay.setTime(dateCCC);



    cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), (new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }), "(" + dtstart + ">" + after + " and " + dtend + "<" + endOfDay.getTimeInMillis() + ")", null, "dtstart ASC");
    gCalendar = new ArrayList<GoogleCalendar>();
    try {
        System.out.println("Count=" + cursor.getCount());

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            System.out.println("the control is just inside of the cursor.count loop");
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                GoogleCalendar googleCalendar = new GoogleCalendar();
                gCalendar.add(googleCalendar);
                int calendar_id = cursor.getInt(0);
                googleCalendar.setCalendar_id(calendar_id);
                String title = cursor.getString(1);
                googleCalendar.setTitle(title);
                String description = cursor.getString(2);
                googleCalendar.setDescription(description);
                String dtstart1 = cursor.getString(3);
                googleCalendar.setDtstart(dtstart1);
                String dtend1 = cursor.getString(4);
                googleCalendar.setDtend(dtend1);
                String eventlocation = cursor.getString(5);
                googleCalendar.setEventlocation(eventlocation);

            }
        }
    } catch (AssertionError ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try [OAuth 2.0 service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to properly access the user accounts. Using a service account lets you impersonate users and perform operation on their behalf.

> **Accessing domain calendars as an app**
>
> An app can access domain-owned calendars without requiring user credentials if it authenticates using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). The service account must have the necessary access using [domain-wide authority delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority). In order to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of the user account with the `setServiceAccountUser` method of the `GoogleCredential` factory.

I hope it helps. Goodluck :)